# How to selecting a value in another table with trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I just call a value in another table in SQL Server but I got some problem:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[IdHeadOtomatis] 
ON [dbo].[RollsNumberSimulation]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [RollsNumberSimulation] 
    SET IdHead = (SELECT IdHead 
                  FROM NewCutPlan 
                  WHERE [IdNewCutPlan] = IdNewCutPlan)
    WHERE [IdRollNumber] IN (SELECT [IdRollNumber] FROM Inserted)
END
```

This query can inserted but when insert "IdNewCutPlan" error in this screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Please help,

Thanks,
Bang

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  In the former, it is not possible to modify the same table which caused the trigger to fire.  Such recursive triggers may also be turned off in SQL Server, and might not be advisable there either.

Comment: Any ideas,? How to get a value by id in trigger or else?

Comment: The easiest route might be to think of a logical way to not have to trigger on the calling table.  Perhaps you could handle it in your business logic before it hits the database.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message the problem is that you are trying to compare a single value to multiple values, specifically your subquery is returning more than one value:

```
select IdHead from NewCutPlan where [IdNewCutPlan]=IdNewCutPlan
```

Probably the problem is your predicate `WHERE [IdNewCutPlan]=IdNewCutPlan` which will always evaluate to true, you could have just written `WHERE 1=1`. Perhaps you meant for one of those to be a literal string `'IdNewCutPlan'` but without more info what you are really trying to do with your trigger it is hard to guess.

Comment: Any ideas,? How to get a value by id in trigger or else?

Comment: @Bang I can't recommend anything because you haven't provided much context in the question. What are the tables for, when is data being inserted that will trigger the trigger, and what are you trying to achieve by having the trigger. Update the question with these and we can give more specific advice.